# How to overwrite fetch using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I want to test my React app and mock the backend calls. I decided to replace fetch by a Jest function that returns a constant.

The problem is that I can't overwrite the default fetch value. I googled a bunch and found `global.fetch = ...` to overwrite fetch but I'm not sure what global means. I tried just writing `var fetch = ...` in my test file but did not work although the component is within the scope of component.

I'm happy to hear alternative solutions for mocking fetch.

```
// Does not work
import component that fetches
test(...){
  var fetch = ...
  <component that fetches/>
}
```

```
// Works
import component that fetches
test(...){
  global.fetch = ...
  <component that fetches/>
}
```

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56355434/how-to-check-the-response-from-global-fetch-in-jest-test-case

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava Do you know what global mean?

Comment: I am not an expert but seems like global is a object and global.fetch is function declared for global which means it is not technically overwriting previous definition

Comment: I think it is referenced to this https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global

Comment: global.fetch definitely overwrite the fetch.

Comment: From the link you provided, it states that variables will only be assessible within modules if not exported. Thus I need to use global to allow variables to accessed cross modules. Thanks for the link. I didn't know global is a node.js thing. Kinda hard to keep track of the functionality between vanilla js, react, and node.

Comment: Yes, `global` is Node and it's much better to be aware of it because Jest is Node app and has a lot of Node-specific things. In Jest environment, `global === window` because it tries to mimic a browser, roughly by setting `global.window = global`. You can access a global as `window.fetch` if it suits you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expected that the first option doesn't work because `fetch` variable is local to a function where it was defined. *although the component is within the scope of component* statement doesn't make much sense, that a component is nested (or more specifically, React element, because `<Comp/>` translates to `React.createElement(Comp)`) doesn't mean it can access anything from that scope except variables that were specifically passed as props.

This works like:

```
function foo() {
  var fetch = 'local';
  var someGlobal = 'local';
  console.log(fetch); // a global shadowed by a local
  console.log(someGlobal); // a global shadowed by a local
  bar(someGlobal);
}

function bar(someGlobal) {
  console.log(fetch); // a global
  console.log(someGlobal); // a global shadowed by a local
}
```

Since real requests aren't supposed to be performed in tests, it's acceptable to mock `fetch` by assigning it to a global like `global.fetch = ...`, but for other globals this would it impossible to restore original implementation. Generally, Jest spies should never be set by assignment. Instead, `spyOn` is used:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch').mockImplementation(...)
});
```

This allows the framework to restore original implementation if needed, this spy works correctly with both `resetAllMocks` and `restoreAllMocks`.