# How to mock multiple promise .then in react hooks and check for state set in one .then

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The question could be seen as similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56355434/how-to-check-the-response-from-global-fetch-in-jest-test-case) but is not working really the same way as that one is checking for a function to be called while im looking for a state to change.

The code i have is this one (headers and body are not really important in this case):

```
const useGetToken = () => {
    const [token, setToken] = useState();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState();

    const fetchToken = useCallback(() => {
        setLoading(true);

        fetch('http://localhost.something', {
            headers,
            body,
        })
            .then((response) => {
                response.json();
            })
            .then((response) => {
                setToken(response.access_token);
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                setError(e);
            })
            .finally(() => {
                setLoading(false);
            });
    }, []);

    return { fetchToken, token, error, loading };
};
```

what I am trying to find is a way to test that the output I have is the correct one in case of success and in case of error.

Seems like I can mock until the first .then but then i dont know how to mock the second one.

```
import { renderHook, act } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';

describe('useGetToken', () => {
  it('should fetch and return a token', () => {
    global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() =>
      Promise.resolve({
        json: () => ({ access_token: 'aToken' }),
      }),
    );

    const { result } = renderHook(() => useGetToken());

    // also how to check for the fetchToken function to equal to itself i dont know how to do 
    // or maybe i can check if it is just a function
    expect(result.current).toEqual({ token: 'aToken', loading: false, error: false });
  });  
});
```

Comment: Not related to the issue but are you sure your `fetchToken` function works correctly? You need to return `response.json();` from the first `then` method's callback function otherwise the next `then` method's callback will receive `undefined` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

managed a way to fix it changing with async await and the correct act.
also changed the double .then in the file to this

```
.then((response) => {
   const parsedResponse = response.json();
   setToken(parsedResponse.access_token);
})
```

cause i didnt need two

```
import { renderHook, act } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import useGetToken from '../useGetVfsToken';

describe('useGetToken', () => {
  it('should fetch when fetchToken is called', async () => {
    global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() =>
      Promise.resolve({
        json: () => ({ access_token: 'aToken123' }),
      }),
    );

    const { result } = renderHook(() => useGetToken());

    expect(window.fetch).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    await act(async () => {
      result.current.fetchToken();
    });

    expect(window.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(result.current.token).toEqual('aToken123');
    expect(result.current.loading).toEqual(false);
    expect(result.current.error).toBeUndefined();
  });

  it('should have an error', async () => {
    const error = 'an error text';

    global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.reject(error));

    const { result } = renderHook(() => useGetToken());

    await act(async () => {
      result.current.fetchToken();
    });

    expect(result.current.error).toEqual(error);
    expect(result.current.loading).toEqual(false);
  });
});
```